# How can I write a simple Regular Expression to search a text file for two strings in any order?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

If my file contents are: `ABC DEF GHI JKL MNO PQR STU VWXYZ`, how can I search this file with a simple regex to see if it contains: `ABC` and `DEF`?

I need the following scenarios two work:

1. `ABC`, `DEF` [true]
2. `BAC`, `ABC` [false]
3. `DEF`, `ABC` [true]
4. `CDE`, `ABC` [false]

Ultimately I'm searching through thousands of files to see if they contain two words.  I can match one easy enough, but not two.

**Update**

I also need this Regex to work over multiple lines.  So if the first string is located on line 1 and the second on line 100, I still need the regex to match.  I'm using [Boost Syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) for Regular Expressions in my text editor: SublimeText2.

**Update 2**

Answer: `(?s)(abc.*def|def.*abc)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are searching for distinct words, it is important to use word boundaries:

```
(\bABC\b.*?\bDEF\b|\bDEF\b.*?\bABC\b)
```

Otherwise you will match `ABCDEF` or `ABC DEFINITION`

Comment: Thanks Will.  Can you help me understand how this can work over multiple lines?

Comment: You're going to have to add a flag, dependent on whatever regex implementation you are using, to allow multi-line matching.  What language are you using?

Comment: Boost syntax for regex: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html

Comment: It looks like flags are discussed here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/syntax_option_type/syntax_option_type_perl.html  It seems like you will need the `mod_s` flag, but you'll have to test to be sure.

Comment: Thanks!  I got it to work as you suggested with `(?s)(abc.*def|def.*abc)`

Answer (score 3):

Use alternation to check for the strings in either order, separated by anything:

```
ABC.*DEF|DEF.*ABC
```

Comment: Will this search work if the file contents are on multiple lines?  So far I'm only able to return results if the two strings are found on the same line.  Sorry this wasn't in the original question.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure the SO protocol on this.  Your answer was exactly correct, and first.  However, I needed additional help to get it to work over newlines.  Therefore I awarded the green checkmark to Will because he also helped me get to the answer, including ignoring newlines.  I really appreciate your help though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -P  -l -z -i 'abc[\w\s]*def|def[\w\s]*abc' *
```

You should be able to use something like the above.

-P is needed for the advanced regex features from PCRE.

-l will make it list a matching file by name.

-z will make it ignore end of lines in the match.

-i will make it case insensitive.

However, it may be a little bit overkill depending the details of your needs.

Likewise, is specific to PCRE-style regexes using grep.

In other tools you might not need to suppress the EOL character, etc.

Haven't accounted for word boundaries.